# Prepared Statements and sanitizing data

Tags: asp-classic, prepared-statement

When using a prepared statement with Classic ASP such as this:

```
SQL = "SELECT user_name, user_sign_up_date FROM tbl_users WHERE this = ? AND id = ? "

Set stmt01 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
stmt01.ActiveConnection = oConn
stmt01.Prepared = true
stmt01.commandtext = SQL
stmt01.Parameters.Append stmt01.CreateParameter("@x1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, card_pwd)
stmt01.Parameters.Append stmt01.CreateParameter("@x2", adInteger, adParamInput, , this_id)
set myRS = stmt01.Execute
```

Apart from doing the usual sense checking to e.g. make sure that a number is a number and so on, does the process of using this kind of Parameterised Statement mean that I no longer have to worry about, e.g. for a varchar or text field, sanitising the data input from users - e.g. would I no longer need to use a function to push everything input by a user through `Server.HTMLencode`?

I'm not sure if the parameterised statement route means I can be less strict re. sanitizing user data now?

Comment: What does it mean "sanitizing"? Are you talking about SQL injection ot HTML injection?

Comment: @Dharman [Data Sanitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Preventing_problems).

Comment: @Lankymart Don't link Wikipedia to me. I meant in OP's specific case. Sanitation is such a broad and meaningless word that it could mean anything. What is OP trying to sanitize and why?

Comment: @Dharman thanks for your reply. I guess I meant HTML sanitising since as far as I know sql injections will be prevented or avoided when using parameterised statements. Probably though I am asking a vague and irritating question. If so, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are conflating two different types of sanitisation. SQL parameterization prevents the “Bobby Tables” vulnerability — a maliciously written bit of data that tricks SQL into ending the current query and executing a separate query of the attacker’s choosing.

https://bobby-tables.com

Even with SQL parameters, an attacker could try to run a script on your page by (for example) entering “alert(‘Gotcha!’)” in a field. Display the field data on an HTML page and that script is written out and executed.   To prevent *that* you use `Server.HTMLencode`

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is SQL injection attacks then parameterization should remove the possibility of the SQL string being tampered with because the values are supplied at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Others are correct that you don't need to worry about the *contents* of the parameters. You do have to worry about the length of strings. I would pass `Left(card_pwd, 255)` to `CreateParameter()` to avoid exceptions crashing your script. I tend to not worry about calling `IsNumeric()` on integer parameters but that might be worthwhile (try passing nonsense and see what happens).